# buck or booster converter, difference between R RL load

Tags: dc, dc-dc-converter

I understand the concept of buck or booster converter but I can't find source about what changes if the load is rl instead of just R. Could you help me to see what changes in the characteristics?

At buck converter if my understanding is right it's just the RL load is just L in series with the converter's L.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "load is rl instead of just R"? Are you talking about an inductive load? Can you draw a schematic to avoid confusion?

Comment: I mean a load with inductivity and resistance, like a coil for a BLDC

Answer (score 1):

Whether you talk about a boost or a buck converter, it can be loaded by various types of load but let's assume a resistance \$R\$. In the literature, you often find \$L\$, \$C\$ and \$R\$ for the constitutive elements:

[image]

Then, if you consider energy-storing elements parasitics like their equivalent series resistance or ESR, writers use lowercase to designate these: \$r_C\$ and \$r_L\$ respectively for the capacitor and the inductor. The sketch for a boost converter thus updates to:

[image]

The load resistance can be labeled whatever you want but \$R\$, \$R_L\$ or \$R_{load}\$ will do just fine as long as you respect lower and uppercase notations for consistency.

Comment: The question sounds like this: show the buck or booster converter with R, RL load, I'm not sure what implies but I suspect that it want to mean that there is inductivity with parallel to R on your first picture.

Answer (score 0):

In general, a DC-DC converter with feedback and good phase margin can handle a wide range of loads.

An inductive load is no exception.  Of course an inductor across a DC source will eventually become a near short circuit, and the load will look like whatever series resistance there is.

If the load is disconnected while the inductor is storing energy, and there's no path for the current then there's the potential for damage as the voltage increases, possibly causing arcing.

You wouldn't normally connect the winding of a BLDC directly to a DC-DC converter, it typically would serve no purpose to do so.  A BLDC motor is normally driven by a (e.g.) 3 phase FET bridge to provide the rotating field that turns the motor.

I'm not sure what you mean by "the RL load is just L in series with the converter's L".  The load is clearly NOT in series with the converter's inductor.  In the boost shown it's after the switch node and in parallel with the output capacitors.  In a buck, it's also in parallel with the output caps.

Comment: Okay, the windings as example was rather bad, right. This is what I think the question is about. At the right side of the circuit.
https://image.slidesharecdn.com/pe-1en96-170228070715/95/half-wave-control-rectifier-with-rl-load-5-638.jpg?cb=1488265719